# Where can I find information related to euclidean spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

Can you please list some sources where I can study the euclidean space(I am a beginner). Sincerely, I've been trying to understand its meaning and all these symbols, but even the material from the university didnt help. Thank you very much !